# Setting ttl on a mongoDB collection - in application or shell?

Tags: java, mongodb

I would like to set the ttl for a collection *once*, what is the idiomatic way of achieving this when building a java application that uses mongoDB? Do ppl simply apply settings like these in the shell? Or in the application code is it normal to check if a collection is already in the DB, if it is not then create it with the desired options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I never do index building in my application code anymore.

I confess that I used to. Everytime my application started up I would ensure all my indexes, until suddenly one day a beginner developer got hold of my code and accidently deleted a character within one of my index sequences.

Consequently the entire cluster froze and went down due to processing, in the foreground, this index building. Fortunately I had a number of delayed and non-index building slaves to repair from but still, I lost about 12 hours all in all and in turn 12 hours of business.

I would recommend you don't do your index building in the application code but instead carfully within your `mongo` console. That goes for any operation like this, even TTL indexing.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, we'll be doing the same.

Comment: Although this is an old thread, the answers are still relevant.  However, will this approach work in a clustered environment?  Maybe yes, with great difficulty because you'd have to know which is the primary node before you could do this operation on the console. If you use a deployment tool then you have to configure it to do the querying of who is the primary before you can then apply the ttl.  If you have no cluster then sure the console approach using a js file would be fine.

Comment: I would say if you gave a cluster you should, as you hinted, use a tool that can correctly manage the cluster and its properties. Indexing gets 100x more complex in clusters

Comment: Wonder how the change has managed to slip through the code review before landing in production... :-)

Comment: @RZet no one is infallible, even my own coding I've noticed problems like this, sometimes an error can make it to prod, and with typos it can be almost impossible to see them since your mind is likely to read it correctly even on review (you can read English by just the first and last letter, scientists found that most people do) so it is very easy for it to get through

Answer (score 0):

You can set a TTL on a collection as documented [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/).

Using the Java driver, I would try:

```
theTTLCollection.ensureIndex(new BasicDBObject("status", 1), new BasicDBObject("expireAfterSeconds", 3600));
```

hth.

Comment: Sorry my question is a bit unclear. I was more looking for *when* this should be done in an application. Is it normal for applications to have an init() where collections are setup in the DB (if they are not already there)? As I only want to apply a setting like this once, not every time I add a record to the collection.)

Answer (score -1):

Setting a [TTL](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/expire-data/)
 is an index operation, so I guess that it would not be wise performance wise to do it every time your code is running.

Comment: if run multiple times it will be registered a no-op as such no performance problems will be seen really